# When do roots of three quadratic polynomials multiply to 1?

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations, quadratics, nonlinear-system

Say I have a trio of quadratic polynomials $p_1,p_2,p_3$. Under what conditions will I have $r_1r_2r_3 = 1$ where each $p_i(r_i) = 0$?

In other words, when does the following nonlinear system have a solution?

$$ p_1(r_1) = 0, \ p_2(r_2) = 0, \ p_3(r_3) = 0, \ r_1r_2r_3 = 1 $$

---

First of all, I know that I can write out the three polynomials, solve them, multiply their coefficients, and set that equal to $1$ for a condition, but this turns out to be quite messy and includes $8$ different cases, corresponding to the choice of root from each polynomial. I'm hoping to find something a bit more elegant, if it exists.

I can see that this is equivalent to asking when there exists $r_1,r_2$ such that $p_3(r_1^{-1}r_2^{-1}) = 0$, or similarly for other combinations. However, this doesn't really change much as far as I can tell. Again, I can solve, invert, multiply, and substitute to get a condition, this time cleaner and with only $4$ cases, but it's still far messier than I'm hoping for.

This problem came up while looking for the conditions under which a bivariate quadratic has a factorization into two bivariate linears. I believe there is an equivalence between these two sets of conditions, so if there is a known condition for that, it should also be sufficient here.

I've poked around with this for quite a while trying to figure it out, but I haven't gotten anywhere. A particular set of equations I was working with is

$$ 6x^2−8x−1=0 \\ y^2−y−6=0 \\ z^2+3z+1=0 \\ xyz = 1 $$

I know that this does not have any solutions, but I can only show it by direct computation of the roots. This one isn't too bad since the $y$ equation has integer roots, but that's obviously not the case in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\mathbb{K}$ be a field with algebraic closure $\overline{\mathbb{K}}$.  For constants $a_i,b_i,c_i\in\mathbb{K}$ for $i\in\{1,2,3\}$ such that none of $a_1$, $a_2$, and $a_3$ is equal to $0$, there exist $x_1,x_2,x_3\in\overline{\mathbb{K}}$ such that $x_1x_2x_3=1$ and
$$a_i\,x_i^2+b_i\,x_i+c_i=0$$
for every $i=1,2,3$ if and only if

- for no $i\in\{1,2,3\}$, $b_i=c_i=0$, and
- the following [riesengroße](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/riesengro%C3%9F) equality holds
  $$\begin{align}&a_1^4 a_2^4 c_3^4
  +4 a_1^3 a_2^3 a_3 c_1 c_2 c_3^3
  +a_1^3 a_2^3 b_1 b_2 b_3 c_3^3
  -2 a_1^3 a_2^3 b_3^2 c_1 c_2 c_3^2
  -2 a_1^3 a_2^2 a_3 b_2^2 c_1 c_3^3
  \\
  &\phantom{a}+a_1^3 a_2^2 b_2^2 b_3^2 c_1 c_3^2
  -2 a_1^2 a_2^3 a_3 b_1^2 c_2 c_3^3
  +a_1^2 a_2^3 b_1^2 b_3^2 c_2 c_3^2
  +6 a_1^2 a_2^2 a_3^2 c_1^2 c_2^2 c_3^2
  +a_1^2 a_2^2 a_3 b_1^2 b_2^2 c_3^3
  \\&\phantom{aa}-5 a_1^2 a_2^2 a_3 b_1 b_2 b_3 c_1 c_2 c_3^2
  -4 a_1^2 a_2^2 a_3 b_3^2 c_1^2 c_2^2 c_3
  +a_1^2 a_2^2 b_1 b_2 b_3^3 c_1 c_2 c_3
  +a_1^2 a_2^2 b_3^4 c_1^2 c_2^2 
  \\&\phantom{aaa}
  -4 a_1^2 a_2 a_3^2 b_2^2 c_1^2 c_2 c_3^2
  +a_1^2 a_2 a_3 b_1 b_2^3 b_3 c_1 c_3^2
  +a_1^2 a_3^2 b_2^4 c_1^2 c_3^2
  -4 a_1 a_2^2 a_3^2 b_1^2 c_1 c_2^2 c_3^2
  \\&\phantom{aaaa}
  +a_1 a_2^2 a_3 b_1^3 b_2 b_3 c_2 c_3^2
  +4 a_1 a_2 a_3^3 c_1^3 c_2^3 c_3
  -5 a_1 a_2 a_3^2 b_1 b_2 b_3 c_1^2 c_2^2 c_3
  -2 a_1 a_2 a_3^2 b_3^2 c_1^3 c_2^3 
  \\&\phantom{aaaaa}
  +a_1 a_2 a_3 b_1^2 b_2^2 b_3^2 c_1 c_2 c_3
  +a_1 a_2 a_3 b_1 b_2 b_3^3 c_1^2 c_2^2 
  -2 a_1 a_3^3 b_2^2 c_1^3 c_2^2 c_3
  +a_1 a_3^2 b_1 b_2^3 b_3 c_1^2 c_2 c_3
  \\&\phantom{aaaaaa}
  +a_1 a_3^2 b_2^2 b_3^2 c_1^3 c_2^2 
  +a_2^2 a_3^2 b_1^4 c_2^2 c_3^2
  -2 a_2 a_3^3 b_1^2 c_1^2 c_2^3 c_3
  +a_2 a_3^2 b_1^3 b_2 b_3 c_1 c_2^2 c_3
  \\&\phantom{aaaaaaa}+a_2 a_3^2 b_1^2 b_3^2 c_1^2 c_2^3 
  +a_3^4 c_1^4 c_2^4 +a_3^3 b_1^2 b_2^2 c_1^2 c_2^2 c_3+a_3^3 b_1 b_2 b_3 c_1^3 c_2^3 \phantom{a}=\phantom{a}0\,.\tag{*}\end{align}$$

The idea is to note that the polynomial $q(t)$ with roots of the form $r_1^\pm r_2^\pm$, where $r_i^{+}$ and $r_i^-$ for $i=1,2,3$ are defined as in [Somos's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3755739/72152) is given by
$$q(t):=a_1^2a_2^2\,t^4-a_1a_2b_1b_2\,t^3+(a_1b_2^2c_1+a_2b_1^2c_2-2a_1a_2c_1c_2)\,t^2-b_1b_2c_1c_2\,t+c_1^2c_2^2\,.$$
(A proof of this claim can be inferred from Example V of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3755995).)

The polynomial $\tilde{q}(t)$ with roots $\dfrac{1}{r_1^{\pm}r_2^{\pm}}$ is given by
$$\tilde{q}(t):=t^4\,q\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)=a_1^2a_2^2-a_1a_2b_1b_2\,t+(a_1b_2^2c_1+a_2b_1^2c_2-2a_1a_2c_1c_2)\,t^2-b_1b_2c_1c_2\,t^3+c_1^2c_2^2\,t^4\,.$$
Hence, there exist such $x_1$, $x_2$, and $x_3$ if and only if $\tilde{q}(r_3^+)=0$ or $\tilde{q}(r_3^-)=0$.  Therefore, this is equivalent to saying
$$a_3^8\,\tilde{q}(r_3^+)\,\tilde{q}(r_3^-)=0\,.$$
If $c_3\neq 0$, then the requirement is
$$\frac{a_3^8}{c_3^4}\,\tilde{q}(r_3^+)\,\tilde{q}(r_3^-)=0\,,$$
which is precisely (*).  If $c_3=0$, then $b_3\neq 0$ must hold and we need to check whether $\tilde{q}\left(-\dfrac{b_3}{a_3}\right)=0$, and this is equivalent to $$\dfrac{a_3^8}{b_3^4}\,\tilde{q}\left(-\dfrac{b_3}{a_3}\right)=0\,.$$
The equation above is precisely (*) when $c_3=0$.

Comment: Nice! I also found a paper which claims that two polynomials $f,g$ are relatively prime iff at least one of $\text{det} \ f(C(g))$ and $\text{det} \ g(C(f))$ vanishes. I haven't done the working out but I suspect that applying that with $\tilde{q}$ and $p_3$ will likely yield the same results. I'm somewhat disappointed that there's not a clean way to get to the result, but that's math sometimes. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: I am curious: what does $f\big(C(g)\big)$ mean?

Comment: By the way, if Somos wrote the whole expansion of the product at the end, I think the answer is most likely the same as mine.

Comment: $C(g)$ is the companion matrix for the polynomial $g$: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix.

The paper I saw was this one: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1099465.

And yes, I do believe the expansions are the same. I think your answer includes a bit more helpful detail which is why I chose it as the accepted one, but both answers are great.

Answer (score 2):

Your question asks if you have three **quadratic** polynomials
$$ p_1(x)\!:=\!a_1 x^2+b_1 x+c_1, \;\;
   p_2(x)\!:=\!a_2 x^2+b_2 x+c_2, \;\;
   p_3(x)\!:=\!a_3 x^3+b_3 x+c_3 $$
with three pairs of roots
$$ p_1(r_1^+) = p_1(r_1^-) = 0, \quad
   p_2(r_2^+) = p_2(r_2^-) = 0, \quad
   p_3(r_3^+) = p_3(r_3^-) = 0  $$
where for $\,n=1,2,3,\,$
$$ r_n^{\,\pm} := \frac{-b_n\pm\sqrt{b_n^2-4a_n c_n}}{2a_n}, $$
then what is the condition that $\, r_1 r_2 r_3 = 1\,$ for some
choice of the roots as given in terms of the coefficients of the
three polynomials? The answer is given by a homogeneous degree
$12$ polynomial expanded out with $34$ monomial terms
$$ P := (a_1a_2a_3)^4 \prod_{i,j,k=\pm} 
 (1 - r_1^{\,i}\,r_2^{\,j}\,r_3^{\,k}) = 
 (a_1a_2a_3)^4 + \dots + (c_1c_2c_3)^4 $$ where the $\,\dots\,$
represents the other $32$ degree-$12$ monomial terms. I used a
computer algebra system to get the expansion. As stated in the
question

> this turns out to be quite messy

and I don't think it can be simplified except for special cases,
but I have been wrong before, so maybe there is hope.

Comment: I think the process can be *simplified* somewhat.  Assuming that $a_1$ and $a_2$ are nonzero, there exists a monic quartic $q(x)$ whose roots are of the form $r_1^{\pm}r_2^{\pm}$.  The coefficients of $q(x)$ can be written *easily* in terms of $a_i$, $b_i$, and $c_i$ for $i\in\{1,2\}$.  All that is left is to check whether $\tilde{q}(x):=x^4\,q\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right)$ has a common root with $p_3(x)$.  One can perform a Euclidean algorithm to find the greatest common divisor between $\tilde{q}(x)$ and $p_3(x)$, for example.  Or simply check whether $\tilde{q}\left(r_3^{\pm}\right)=0$.

Comment: @Batominovski Can you elaborate on how to "easily" write the coefficients of $q$? Do you mean something other than expanding the product of the four roots?

Comment: If the first two equations are $$x^2+ax+b=0$$ and
$$y^2+cy+d=0\,,$$ then the quartic is given by $$q(t):=t^4-act^3+(a^2d-2bd+bc^2)t^2+abcdt+b^2d^2\,.$$

Comment: I messed up the sign:  $$q(t):=t^4-act^3+(a^2d-2bd+bc^2)t^2{\color{red}-}abcdt+b^2d^2\,.$$