# Polynomial Big List: Find the polynomial whose roots are given by some functions of the roots of given polynomials.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, reference-request, contest-math, big-list

I would like to create a compilation about polynomials for future reference.  The aim is to capture some scenarios that appear in many exams and contests.  Please feel free to make a contribution.

> **Request.**  For each answer, please give the setting of your problem (the input polynomials, the function, etc) and the output polynomial.  Please also provide a proof, a proof sketch, or a reference for your claim.

The five scenarios I have thought of are listed below.   In what follows, let $\mathbb{K}$ be a field with the algebraic closure $\overline{\mathbb{K}}$.  (For those who have not yet learned about fields, think of $\mathbb{K}$ as $\mathbb{R}$, and $\overline{\mathbb{K}}$ as $\mathbb{C}$.)  For simplicity, all polynomials involved may be assumed to be monic (that is, the leading coefficient is $1$).

> **Scenario I.**  A polynomial $p(x)$ of degree $d$ is given, where $r_1,r_2,\ldots,r_d\in\overline{\mathbb{K}}$ are the roots of $p(x)$.  For a function $f:\overline{\mathbb{K}}\to\overline{\mathbb{K}}$, let $q(x)$ be the polynomial of degree $d$ with roots $f(r_1)$, $f(r_2)$, $\ldots$, $f(r_d)$.  What is $q(x)$ in terms of $p(x)$ and $f$?

**Example I.**

- If $f(t)=\lambda t+\mu$ where $\lambda,\mu\in\mathbb{K}$ with $\lambda\neq 0$, then $q(x)=\lambda^d\,p\left(\dfrac{x-\mu}{\lambda}\right)$.
- If all roots of $p(x)$ are nonzero and $f(t)=\dfrac{1}{t}$ for $t\neq 0$, then $q(x)=\dfrac{x^d}{p(0)}\,p\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right)$.
- If $f(t)=t^2$ and $p(x)=x^2+ax+b$, then $q(x)=x^2-(a^2-2b)x+b^2$.

> **Scenario II.** A polynomial $p(x)$ of degree $d$ is given, where $r_1,r_2,\ldots,r_d\in\overline{\mathbb{K}}$ are the roots of $p(x)$.  For a symmetric function $f:\overline{\mathbb{K}}\times\overline{\mathbb{K}}\to\overline{\mathbb{K}}$, let $q(x)$ be the polynomial of degree $\dfrac{d(d-1)}{2}$ with roots $f(r_i,r_j)$ where $i$ and $j$ are integers such that $1\leq i<j\leq d$.  What is $q(x)$ in terms of $p(x)$ and $f$?

**Example II.**  If $f(t_1,t_2)=t_1+t_2$ and $p(x)=x^3+ax^2+bx+c$, then $$q(x)=x^3+2a\,x^2+(a^2+b)\,x+(ab-c)\,.$$

> **Scenario III.** A polynomial $p(x)$ of degree $d$ is given, where $r_1,r_2,\ldots,r_d\in\overline{\mathbb{K}}$ are the roots of $p(x)$.  For an asymmetric function $f:\overline{\mathbb{K}}\times\overline{\mathbb{K}}\to\overline{\mathbb{K}}$, let $q(x)$ be the polynomial of degree $d(d-1)$ with roots $f(r_i,r_j)$ where $i,j\in\{1,2,\ldots,d\}$ are such that $i\neq j$.  What is $q(x)$ in terms of $p(x)$ and $f$?

**Example III.** If $f(t_1,t_2)=\dfrac{t_1}{t_2}$ and $p(x)=x^2+ax+b$ with $b\neq 0$, then $$q(x)=x^2-\left(\dfrac{a^2}{b}-2\right)\,x+1\,.$$

> **Scenario IV.**  A polynomial $p(x)$ of degree $d$ is given, where $r_1,r_2,\ldots,r_d\in\overline{\mathbb{K}}$ are the roots of $p(x)$.  Let $s>2$ and $f:\overline{\mathbb{K}}^s\to\overline{\mathbb{K}}$ be given.  If $q(x)$ is a polynomial whose roots are given by $f(r_{i_1},r_{i_2},\ldots,r_{i_s})$ where $(i_1,i_2,\ldots,i_s)$ is in some subset $S$ of $\{1,2,\ldots,d\}^s$, then what is $q(x)$ in terms of $p(x)$ and $f$?

**Example IV.**  If $f(t_1,t_2,t_3)=t_1t_2t_3$,  $p(x)=x^4+a_3x^3+a_2x^2+a_1x+a_0$, and $$S=\big\{(1,2,3),(1,2,4),(1,3,4),(2,3,4)\big\}\,,$$ then
$$q(x)=x^4+a_1\,x+a_2a_0\,x+a_3a_0^2\,x+a_0^3\,.$$  More generally, for a given polynomial $p(x)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^d\,a_k\,x^k$ of degree $d>1$, if $$f(t_1,t_2,\ldots,t_{d-1})=t_1t_2\cdots t_{d-1}$$ with $$S=\big\{(i_1,i_2,\ldots,i_{d-1})\,\big|\,1\leq i_1<i_2<\ldots<i_{d-1}\leq d\big\}\,,$$ we have
$$q(x)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^d\,(-1)^{d(d-k)}\,a_{d-k}\,a_0^{d-k-1}\,x^k\,,$$
where we use the conventions $a_0^0=1$ and $a_0\,a_0^{-1}=1$ even if $a_0=0$.

> **Scenario V.**  Polynomials $p_1(x),p_2(x),\ldots,p_n(x)\in\mathbb{K}[x]$ are given, where $p_i(x)$ has degree $d_i$ with roots $r_i^j\in\overline{\mathbb{K}}$ for $j=1,2,\ldots,d_i$.  For a function $f:\overline{\mathbb{K}}^n\to\overline{\mathbb{K}}$, let $q(x)\in\overline{\mathbb{K}}[x]$ be the polynomial of degree $\prod\limits_{i=1}^n\,d_i$ with roots $f\left(r_1^{j_1},r_2^{j_2},\ldots,r_n^{j_n}\right)$ with $j_i\in\{1,2,\ldots,d_i\}$ for every $i=1,2,\ldots,n$.  What is $q(x)$ in terms of $p_1(x),p_2(x),\ldots,p_n(x)$ and $f$?

**Example V.** If $p_1(x)=x^2+a_1x+b_1$, $p_2(x)=x^2+a_2x+b_2$, and $f(t_1,t_2)=t_1t_2$, then $$q(x)=x^4-a_1a_2\,x^3+(a_1^2b_2+a_2^2b_1-2b_1b_2)\,x^2-a_1a_2b_1b_2\,x+b_1^2b_2^2\,.$$

> ***Proof of Example V.***  Recall that $$r_i^1+r_i^2=-a_i\text{ and }r_i^1r_i^2=b_i\text{ for }i\in\{1,2\}\,.$$  Therefore, $$\sum_{j_1,j_2\in\{1,2\}}\,f(r_1^{j_1},r_1^{j_2})=(r_1^1+r_1^2)(r_2^1+r_2^2)=a_1a_2$$ and $$\prod_{j_1,j_2\in\{1,2\}}\,f(r_1^{j_1},r_1^{j_2})=(r_1^1r_1^2)^2(r_2^1r_2^2)^2=b_1^2b_2^2\,.$$  Observe that $$\begin{align}\sum_{\big\{(j_1,j_2),(j'_1,j'_2),(j''_1,j''_2)\big\}\in\binom{\{0,1\}^2}{3}}\,&f(r_1^{j_1},r_2^{j_2})\cdot f(r_1^{j'_1},r_2^{j'_2})\cdot f(r_1^{j''_1},r_2^{j''_2})\\&=b_1b_2\,\sum_{j_1,j_2\in\{1,2\}}\,f(r_1^{j_1},r_1^{j_2})=a_1a_2b_1b_2\,.\end{align}$$  Finally, $$\begin{align}\sum_{\big\{(j_1,j_2),(j'_1,j'_2)\big\}\in\binom{\{0,1\}^2}{2}}\,f(r_1^{j_1},r_2^{j_2})\cdot f(r_1^{j'_1},r_2^{j'_2})&=b_2\,\sum_{j=1}^2\,(r_1^j)^2+b_1\,\sum_{j=1}^2\,(r_2^j)^2+2b_1b_2\\&=b_2(a_1^2-2b_1)+b_1\,(a_2^2-2b_2)+2b_1b_2\\&=a_1^2b_2+a_2^2b_1-2b_1b_2\,.\end{align}$$  The proof is now complete.

Answer (score 2):

This example aligns with **Scenario IV**.  Let $p(x)=x^3+ax^2+bx+c$, $f(t_1,t_2,t_3)=\dfrac{t_1}{t_2}+\dfrac{t_2}{t_3}+\dfrac{t_3}{t_1}$, and $S=\big\{(1,2,3),(1,3,2)\big\}$.  Suppose that $c\neq 0$.  Because $r_1+r_2+r_3=-a$, $r_2r_3+r_3r_1+r_1r_2=b$, and $r_1r_2r_3=-c$, we have
$$f(r_1,r_2,r_3)+f(r_1,r_3,r_2)=-\frac{ab}{c}-3$$
and
$$f(r_1,r_2,r_3)\cdot f(r_1,r_3,r_2)=\frac{a^3c-6abc+b^3}{c^2}+9\,.$$
Therefore,
$$q(x)=x^2+\left(\frac{ab}{c}+3\right)\,x+\left(\frac{a^3c-6abc+b^3}{c^2}+9\right)\,.$$

Answer (score 1):

This example aligns with **Scenario II**.  Let $p(x)=x^3+ax^2+bx+c$ and $f(t_1,t_2)=t_1^2t_2^2$.  Suppose that $c\neq 0$.  Because $r_1+r_2+r_3=-a$, $r_2r_3+r_3r_1+r_1r_2=b$, and $r_1r_2r_3=-c$, we have
$$f(r_1,r_2)+f(r_1,r_3)+f(r_2,r_3)=b^2-2ac\,,$$
$$f(r_1,r_2)\cdot f(r_1,r_3)+f(r_1,r_2)\cdot f(r_2,r_3)+f(r_1,r_3)\cdot f(r_2,r_3)=(a^2-2b)c^2\,,$$
and
$$f(r_1,r_2)\cdot f(r_1,r_3)\cdot f(r_2,r_3)=c^4\,.$$
Therefore,
$$q(x)=x^3-(b^2-2ac)\,x^2+(a^2-2b)c^2\,x-c^4\,.$$

Answer (score 1):

This example aligns with **Scenario I**.  Let $f(t)=\dfrac{\alpha \,t+\beta}{t+\delta}$, where $\alpha\delta\neq \beta$.  Observe that
$$f(t)=\alpha+\frac{\beta-\alpha\delta}{t+\delta}\,.$$
Let $p(x)$ be a given polynomial with roots $r_1,r_2,\ldots,r_d$.  Suppose that $q_1(x)$ is the polynomial with roots $\dfrac{1}{r_i+\delta}$ for $i=1,2,\ldots,d$.  Therefore, we see that
$$q_1(x)=\prod_{i=1}^d\,\left(x-\frac{1}{r_i+\delta}\right)=x^d\,\frac{\prod\limits_{i=1}^d\,\left(\frac{1}{x}-\delta-r_i\right)}{\prod\limits_{i=1}^d\,(-\delta-r_i)}=\dfrac{x^d}{p(-\delta)}\,p\left(\frac{1}{x}-\delta\right)\,.$$
If $q(x)$ is the polynomial with roots $\alpha+\dfrac{\beta-\alpha\delta}{t+\delta}$, then
$$q(x)=(\beta-\alpha\delta)^d\,q_1\left(\frac{x-\alpha}{\beta-\alpha\delta}\right)\,.$$
Consequently,
$$q(x)=\frac{(x-\alpha)^d}{p(-\delta)}\,p\left(\frac{\beta-\alpha\delta}{x-\alpha}-\delta\right)=\frac{(x-\alpha)^d}{p(-\delta)}\,p\left(\frac{\beta-\delta x}{x-\alpha}\right)\,.$$

Answer (score 0):

This example aligns with **Scenario V**.  Let $p_1(x)=x^2+a_1x+b_1$, $p_2(x)=x^2+a_2x+b_2$, and $f(t_1,t_2)=\lambda_1t_1+\lambda_2t_2$, where $\lambda_1,\lambda_2\neq 0$.  Then,
$$q(x)=\prod_{j_1=1}^2\,\prod_{j_2=1}^2\,\left(x-\lambda_1r_1^{j_1}-\lambda_2r_2^{j_2}\right)=\prod_{j_1=1}^2\,\lambda_2^2\,\prod_{j_2=1}^2\,\left(\frac{x-\lambda_1r_1^{j_1}}{\lambda_2}-r_2^{j_2}\right)\,.$$
Therefore,
$$q(x)=\prod_{j_1=1}^2\,\lambda_2^2\,p_2\left(\frac{x-\lambda_1\,r_1^{j_1}}{\lambda_2}\right)=\prod_{j_1=1}^2\,\left((x-\lambda_1r_1^{j_1})^2+\lambda_2a_2(x-\lambda_1r_1^{j_1})+\lambda_2^2b_2\right)\,.$$
Note that
$$\begin{align}(x-\lambda_1r_1^{j_1})^2&+\lambda_2a_2(x-\lambda_1r_1^{j_1})+\lambda_2^2b_2
\\&=x^2+\lambda_2a_2x+\lambda_2^2b_2-\left(2\lambda_1x+\lambda_1\lambda_2 a_2\right)r_1^{j_1}+\lambda_1^2(r_1^{j_1})^2\,.\end{align}$$
Now, if $r$ is a root of $p_1(x)$, then
$$r^2=-a_1r-b_1\,,$$
whence
$$\begin{align}(x-\lambda_1r_1^{j_1})^2&+\lambda_2a_2(x-\lambda_1r_1^{j_1})+\lambda_2^2b_2
\\&=x^2+\lambda_2a_2x+\lambda_2^2b_2-\left(2\lambda_1x+\lambda_1\lambda_2 a_2\right)r_1^{j_1}-\lambda_1^2\left(a_1r_1^{j_1}+b_1\right)
\\&=\left(x^2+\lambda_2a_2x+\lambda_2^2b_2-\lambda_1^2b_1\right)-\left(2\lambda_1x+\lambda_1\lambda_2 a_2+\lambda_1^2a_1\right)r_1^{j_1}\,.\end{align}$$
That is,
$$q(x)=\left(2\lambda_1x+\lambda_1\lambda_2 a_2+\lambda_1^2a_1\right)^2\,\prod_{j_1=1}^2\,\left(\frac{x^2+\lambda_2a_2x+\lambda_2^2b_2-\lambda_1^2b_1}{2\lambda_1x+\lambda_1\lambda_2 a_2+\lambda_1^2a_1}-r_1^{j_1}\right)\,.$$
That is,
$$q(x)=\left(2\lambda_1x+\lambda_1\lambda_2 a_2+\lambda_1^2a_1\right)^2\,p_1\left(\frac{x^2+\lambda_2a_2x+\lambda_2^2b_2-\lambda_1^2b_1}{2\lambda_1x+\lambda_1\lambda_2 a_2+\lambda_1^2a_1}\right)\,.$$
Ergo,
$$\begin{align}q(x)&=\left(x^2+\lambda_2a_2x+\lambda_2^2b_2-\lambda_1^2b_1\right)^2
\\&\phantom{abcd}+a_1\left(x^2+\lambda_2a_2x+\lambda_2^2b_2-\lambda_1^2b_1\right)\left(2\lambda_1x+\lambda_1\lambda_2 a_2+\lambda_1^2a_1\right)
\\&\phantom{abcdefg}+b_1\left(2\lambda_1x+\lambda_1\lambda_2 a_2+\lambda_1^2a_1\right)^2
\\
&=x^4
+2\left(\lambda_1a_1+\lambda_2a_2\right)\,x^3
\\&\phantom{abcd}+\left(\lambda_1^2\alpha_1^2+\lambda_2^2\alpha_2^2+3\lambda_1\lambda_2\alpha_1\alpha_2+2\lambda_1^2b_1+2\lambda_2^2b_2\right)\,x^2
\\&\phantom{abcdefg}+\left(\lambda_1^2\lambda_2a_1^2a_2+\lambda_1\lambda_2^2a_1a_2^2+2\lambda_1^3a_1b_1+2\lambda_2^2a_2b_2+2\lambda_1^2\lambda_2a_2b_1+2\lambda_1\lambda_2^2a_1b_2\right)x
\\&\phantom{abcdfghijk}+\left(\lambda_1^3\lambda_2a_1a_2b_1+\lambda_1\lambda_2^3a_1a_2b_2+\lambda_1^2\lambda_2^2a_1^2b_2+\lambda_1^2\lambda_2^2a_2^2b_1+\lambda_1^4b_1^2+\lambda_2^4b_2^2-2\lambda_1^2\lambda_2^2b_1b_2\right)\,.\end{align}$$
In particular, if $\lambda_1=\lambda_2=1$, we have
$$\begin{align}q(x)&=x^4+2(a_1+a_2)\,x^3+(a_1^2+3a_1a_2+a_2^2+2b_1+2b_2)\,x^2
\\&\phantom{abcd}+(a_1^2a_2+a_1a_2^2+2a_1b_1+2a_2b_2+2a_1b_2+2a_2b_1)\,x\\&\phantom{abcdefg}+(a_1a_2b_1+a_1a_2b_2+a_1^2b_2+a_2^2b_1+b_1^2-2b_1b_2+b_2^2)\,.\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

This example aligns with **Scenario III**.  Let $p(x)=x^2+ax+b$ and $f(t_1,t_2)=\lambda t_1+\mu t_2$, where $\lambda,\mu\neq0$ and $\lambda\neq \mu$. Because $r_1+r_2=-a$ and $r_1r_2=b$, we get
$$f(r_1,r_2)+f(r_2,r_1)=(\lambda+\mu)(r_1+r_2)=-(\lambda+\mu)a$$
and
$$f(r_1,r_2)\cdot f(r_2,r_1)=\lambda\mu(r_1^2+r_2^2)+(\lambda^2+\mu^2)r_1r_2=\lambda\mu(a^2-2b)+(\lambda^2+\mu^2)b\,.$$
Hence,
$$q(x)=x^2+(\lambda+\mu)a\,x+\left(\lambda\mu a^2+(\lambda-\mu)^2 b\right)\,.$$

Answer (score 0):

This example aligns with **Scenario IV**.  Let $p(x)=x^4+a_3x^3+a_2x^2+a_1x+a_0$, $$f(t_1,t_2,t_3,t_4)=t_1t_2+t_3t_4\,,$$and $S=\big\{(1,2,3,4),(1,3,2,4),(1,4,2,3)\big\}$.  Because $$r_1+r_2+r_3+r_4=-a_3\,,$$ $$r_1r_2+r_1r_3+r_1r_4+r_2r_3+r_2r_4+r_3r_4=a_2\,,$$ $$r_1r_2r_3+r_1r_2r_4+r_1r_3r_4+r_2r_3r_4=-a_1\,,$$ and $$r_1r_2r_3r_4=a_0\,,$$ we have
$$f(r_1,r_2,r_3,r_4)+f(r_1,r_3,r_2,r_4)+f(r_1,r_4,r_2,r_3)=a_2\,,$$
$$\begin{align}f(r_1,r_2,r_3,r_4)\cdot f(r_1,r_3,r_2,r_4)&+f(r_1,r_2,r_3,r_4)\cdot f(r_1,r_4,r_2,r_3)+f(r_1,r_3,r_2,r_4)\cdot f(r_1,r_4,r_2,r_3)
\\&=a_3a_1-4a_0\,,\end{align}$$
and
$$f(r_1,r_2,r_3,r_4)\cdot f(r_1,r_3,r_2,r_4)\cdot f(r_1,r_4,r_2,r_3)=a_3^2a_0+a_1^2-4a_2a_0\,.$$
Therefore,
$$q(x)=x^3-a_2\,x^2+\left(a_3a_1-4a_0\right)\,x-\left(a_3^2a_0+a_1^2-4a_2a_0\right)\,.$$

Answer (score 0):

This example aligns with **Scenario I**.  Let $f(t)=f_2t^2+f_1t+f_0$, where $f_2 \neq 0$.  Let $p(x)$ be a given polynomial with roots $r_1,r_2,\ldots,r_d$.  Suppose that $q(x)$ is the polynomial with roots $f(r_i)$ for $i=1,2,\ldots,d$.  Therefore, we see that
$$q(x)=\prod_{i=1}^d\,\left(x-f_2r_i^2-f_1r_i-f_0\right)=(-1)^df_2^d\,\prod\limits_{i=1}^d\,\left(r_i^2+\frac{f_1}{f_2}r_i+\frac{f_0}{f_2}-\frac{x}{f_2}\right)\,.$$
Ergo,
$$q(x)=(-1)^df_2^d\,\prod_{i=1}^d\,\left(r_i-\frac{-f_1+\sqrt{f_1^2-4f_2f_0+4f_2x}}{2f_2}\right)\left(r_i-\frac{-f_1-\sqrt{f_1^2-4f_2f_0+4f_2x}}{2f_2}\right)\,,$$
making
$$q(x)=(-1)^df_2^d\,p\left(\frac{-f_1+\sqrt{f_1^2-4f_2f_0+4f_2x}}{2f_2}\right)\,p\left(\frac{-f_1-\sqrt{f_1^2-4f_2f_0+4f_2x}}{2f_2}\right)\,.$$
If the polynomial $\tilde{p}(x)$ whose roots are given by $\left(r_i+\dfrac{f_1}{2f_2}\right)^2$ for $i=1,2,\ldots,d$ is known, then
$$q(x)=f_2^d\,\tilde{p}\left(\frac{4f_2x+f_1^2-4f_2f_0}{4f_2^2}\right)\,.$$
In particular, if $p(x)=x^2+ax+b$, then
$$\tilde{p}(x)=x^2-\left(a^2-2b-\frac{f_1}{f_2}a+\frac{f_1^2}{2f_2^2}\right)\,x+\left(b-\frac{f_1}{2f_2}a+\frac{f_1^2}{4f_2^2}\right)^2\,,$$
whence
$$\begin{align}q(x)&=x^2 + \left(-a^2f_2 + af_1 + 2bf_2 - 2f_0\right)\,x \\&\phantom{abcd}+ \left(a^2f_0f_2 - abf_1f_2 + b^2f_2^2 - af_0f_1 + bf_1^2 - 2bf_0f_2 + f_0^2\right)\,.\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

This example aligns with **Scenario II**.  Let $p(x)=x^4+ax+b$ and $f(t_1,t_2)=\dfrac{\alpha\,t_1+\beta}{\gamma\,t_2+\delta}$, where $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta\in\mathbb{K}$ are such that $\alpha\neq 0$, $\gamma\neq 0$, and $\gamma^2b-\gamma\delta a+\delta^2\neq 0$.  From $r_1+r_2=-a$ and $r_1r_2=b$, we have
$$\dfrac{\alpha\,r_1+\beta}{\gamma\,r_2+\delta}+\dfrac{\alpha\,r_2+\beta}{\gamma\,r_1+\delta}=\frac{\alpha\gamma(a^2-2b)-(\alpha\delta+\beta\gamma)a+\beta\delta}{\gamma^2b-\gamma\delta a+\delta^2}$$
and
$$\dfrac{\alpha\,r_1+\beta}{\gamma\,r_2+\delta}\cdot\dfrac{\alpha\,r_2+\beta}{\gamma\,r_1+\delta}=\frac{\alpha^2b-\alpha\beta a+\beta^2}{\gamma^2b-\gamma\delta a+\delta^2}\,.$$
Consequently,
$$q(x)=x^2-\frac{\alpha\gamma(a^2-2b)-(\alpha\delta+\beta\gamma)a+\beta\delta}{\gamma^2b-\gamma\delta a+\delta^2}\,x+\frac{\alpha^2b-\alpha\beta a+\beta^2}{\gamma^2b-\gamma\delta a+\delta^2}\,.$$

Answer (score 0):

This example aligns with **Scenario I**.  Let $f(t)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\,f_kt^k$ with $f_n
\neq 0$, and $$p(x)=x^2+ax+b\,.$$  Assume that we know all the roots of $f$:
$$f(t)=f_n\,\prod_{k=1}^n\,(t-\rho_k)\,.$$
Define the [Newton sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities) $(s_m)_{m=0}^\infty$ as follows: $s_0:=2$, $s_1=-a$, and
$$s_m:=-as_{m-1}-bs_{m-2}\,\text{ for }m=2,3,\ldots\,.$$
Then, the polynomial $q(x)$ with roots $f(r_1)$ and $f(r_2)$ is given by
$$q(x)=x^2-\left(\sum_{k=0}^n\,f_ks_k\right)\,x+f_n^2\,\prod_{k=1}^n\,p(\rho_k)\,.$$
In other words,
$$q(x)=x^2-f_n\,\left(\sum_{k=0}^n\,(-1)^{n-k}\,s_k\,\sum_{T\in\binom{[n]}{n-k}}\,\prod_{\nu\in T}\,\rho_\nu\right)\,x+f_n^2\,\prod_{k=1}^n\,p(\rho_k)\,,$$
where $[n]:=\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ and $\displaystyle\binom{[n]}{m}$ is the set of all subsets of $[n]$ of size $m\in\{0,1,2,\ldots,n\}$.

Answer (score 0):

This example aligns with **Scenario III**.  Let $p(x)=x^3+ax^2+bx+c$ and $f(t_1,t_2)=t_1-t_2$. If $q(x)$ is the polynomial with roots $f(r_i,r_j)$ for $i,j\in\{1,2,3\}$ with $i\ne j$, then clearly,
$$q(x)=Q(x^2)\,,$$
where $Q(x)$ is the polynomial with roots $(r_i-r_j)^2$, where $1\leq i<j\leq 3$.  It is not difficult to see that
$$(r_1-r_2)^2+(r_1-r_3)^2+(r_2-r_3)^2=2(a^2-3b)\,,$$
$$\begin{align}(r_1-r_2)^2\cdot (r_1-r_3)^2&+(r_1-r_2)^2\cdot (r_2-r_3)^2+(r_1-r_3)^2\cdot(r_2-r_3)^2
\\&=a^4-6a^2b+9b^2\,,\end{align}$$
and
$$(r_1-r_2)^2\cdot(r_1-r_3)^2\cdot(r_2-r_3)^2=-4a^3c+a^2b^2+18abc-4b^3-27c^2$$
(which is the discriminant of $p(x)$).  Therefore,
$$Q(x)=x^3-2(a^2-3b)\,x^2+(a^4-6a^2b+9b^2)\,x-(-4a^3c+a^2b^2+18abc-4b^3-27c^2)\,,$$
making
$$q(x)=x^6-2(a^2-3b)\,x^4+(a^4-6a^2b+9b^2)\,x^2-(-4a^3c+a^2b^2+18abc-4b^3-27c^2)\,.$$